# How to add parentheses to build a complicated dynamic Django filter with Q()?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-q

I want to build a complicated filter：

```
queryset.filter(
  (Q(k__contains=“1”) & Q(k__contains=“2”) & (~Q(k__contains=“3”))) | 
  (Q(k1__contains=“2”) & (~Q(k4__contains=“3”)))
)
```

The structure is fixed, but the query is dynamic and depends on a case specified by given input.

Tthe input could be for example :

```
(k=1&k=2&~k=3) | (k1=1&~k4=3)
```

or

```
(k=1&~k=3) | (k1=1&~k4=3) | (k=4&~k=3)
```

How to add parentheses to build this query to make it run as expected?

Comment: The question is about parentheses, but the examples are so simple that they would work also without parentheses considering only the priority of operators and you wrote about "fixed" structure and "complicated" filter. Can you please specify more also by examples, how complex or fixed this structure is? Nested parentheses? Constants on the right side of equal sign are numeric only?

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70196305/how-to-create-dynamic-queries-with-django-q-objects-from-parenthesis-inside-a-st?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two answers are presented: one simple and one perfect

## 1) A **simple answer** for similarly simple expressions:

It your expressions are simple and it seems better to read it by a short Python code. The most useful simplification is that parentheses are not nested. Less important simplification is that the operator OR ("|") is never in parentheses. The operator NOT is used only inside parentheses. The operator NOT is never double repeated ("~~").

**Syntax:** I express these simplifications in a form of EBNF syntax rules that could be useful later in a discussion about Python code.

```
expression = term, [ "|", term ];
term       = "(", factor, { "&", factor }, ")";
factor     = [ "~" ], variable, "=", constant;

variable   = "a..z_0..9";           # anything except "(", ")", "|", "&", "~", "="
constant   = "0-9_a-z... ,'\"";     # anything except "(", ")", "|", "&", "~", "="
```

Optional white spaces are handled easily by .strip() method to can freely accept expressions like in mathematics. White spaces inside constants are supported.

**Solution:**

```py
def compile_q(input_expression):
    q_expression = ~Q()  # selected empty
    for term in input_expression.split('|'):
        q_term = Q()     # selected all
        for factor in term.strip().lstrip('(').rstrip(')').split('&'):
            left, right = factor.strip().split('=', 1)
            negated, left = left.startswith('~'), left.lstrip('~')
            q_factor = Q(**{left.strip() + '__contains': right.strip()})
            if negated:
                q_factor = ~q_factor
            q_term &= q_factor
        q_expression |= q_term
    return q_expression
```

The superfluous empty and full Q expressions `~Q()` and `Q()` are finally optimized and eliminated by Django.

**Example:**

```
>>> expression = "(k=1&k=2&~k=3) | ( k1 = 1 & ~ k4 = 3 )"
>>> qs = queryset.filter(compile_q(expression))
```

**Check:**

```
>>> print(str(qs.values('pk').query))        # a simplified more readable sql print
SELECT id FROM ... WHERE
((k LIKE %1% AND k LIKE %2% AND NOT (k LIKE %3%)) OR (k1 LIKE %1% AND NOT (k4 LIKE %3%)))
>>> sql, params = qs.values('pk').query.get_compiler('default').as_sql()
>>> print(sql); print(params)                # a complete parametrized escaped print
SELECT... k LIKE %s ...
[... '%2%', ...]
```

The first "print" is a Django command for simplified more readable SQL without apostrophes and escaping, because it is actually delegated to the driver. The second print is a more complicated parametrized SQL command with all possible safe escaping.

---

## 2) Perfect, but longer solution

This answer can compile **any combination of boolean operators** "|", "&", "~", **any level of nested parentheses** and a comparision operator "=" to a Q() expression:

**Solution:** (not much more complicated)

```py
import ast    # builtin Python parser
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Q


def q_combine(node: ast.AST) -> Q:
    if isinstance(node, ast.Module):
        assert len(node.body) == 1 and isinstance(node.body[0], ast.Expr)
        return q_combine(node.body[0].value)
    if isinstance(node, ast.BoolOp):
        if isinstance(node.op, ast.And):
            q = Q()  # select all rows initially
            for val in node.values:
                q &= q_combine(val)
            return q
        if isinstance(node.op, ast.Or):
            q = ~Q()  # select none row initially
            for val in node.values:
                q |= q_combine(val)
            return q
    if isinstance(node, ast.UnaryOp):
        assert isinstance(node.op, ast.Not)
        return ~q_combine(node.operand)
    if isinstance(node, ast.Compare):
        assert isinstance(node.left, ast.Name)
        assert len(node.ops) == 1 and isinstance(node.ops[0], ast.Eq)
        assert len(node.comparators) == 1 and isinstance(node.comparators[0], ast.Constant)
        return Q(**{node.left.id + '__contains': str(node.comparators[0].value)})
    raise ValueError('unexpected node {}'.format(type(node).__name__))

def compile_q(expression: str) -> Q:
    std_expr = (expression.replace('=', '==').replace('~', ' not ')
                .replace('&', ' and ').replace('|', ' or ').lstrip())
    return q_combine(ast.parse(std_expr))
```

**Example:** the same as in my previous answer a more complex following:

```
>>> expression = "~(~k=1&(k1=2|k1=3|(k=5 & k4=3)))"
>>> qs = queryset.filter(compile_q(expression))
```

The same example gives the same result, a more nested example gives a correct more nested result.

EBNF syntax rules are not important in this case, because no parser is implemented in this solution and the standard Python parser AST is used. It is little different with recursion.

```
expression = term, [ "|", term ];
term       = factor, { "&", factor };
factor     = [ "~" ], variable, "=", constant | [ "~" ],  "(", expression, ")";

variable   = "a..z_0..9";  # any identifier acceptable by Python, e.g. not a Python keyword
constant   = "0-9_a-z... ,'\"";    # any numeric or string literal acceptable by Python
```

Comment: Could you explain please why the ~Q if it is an instance of ast.Or?

Comment: @julianofischer: The meaning of `~Q()` for "OR" operator is an initial value `select none row` (exlude all). An expression `~Q() | Q(condition)` is the same as ` Q(condition)`. It is similar to `Q()` (`select all rows` - exlude none) that is used with AND operator. If you do not like it readable enough you could rewrite it `q = q_combine(node.values[0])` `for val in node.values[1:]: q |= q_combine(val)` but I think that the solution with initial `~Q()` is more elegant. Thanks to you I read the answer again I added two comments and I found two minor bugs that I fixed.

Comment: it is in fact a very elegant and robust solution. Congratulations and thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I failed to make this work using django Q.

Bug use `extra` to build code like

`queryset.extra(where = 
  ["(k1 like '%1%' and k2 like '%2%' and (k3 not like '%3%')) or (k1 like '%4%' and (k3 not like '%3%'))"]
)`

and it works.

Comment: It is strange that it did not work with Q expressions because your solution is exactly how the original with Q expressions would be compiled. You can verify it by `print(str(queryset.query))` (It prints a simplified SQL without escaping and and without apostrophes.) The solution with `extra(where=...)` is unsafe e.g. if the right side of "like" could contain something with an apostrophe. It is fortune and an accident that one solution worked and an equally simple solutions did not.

Comment: @hynekcer  I want to dynamicially build the Q query with parentheses from the changing input, not the fixed query I made by hand.

Comment: @hynekcer the input query can be simple like    k=1&~k=3    or more complicated like  (k=1&~k=3) | (k1=1&~k4=3) | (k=4&~k=3)

Comment: I understand. You didn't parsed the expression and that SQL is created by string replacement.